# Default to "autolist on" in ruby debugger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-debug

Is there a way to set up certain defaults in the debugger?  I'm not finding a way to do this..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

create the file ~/.rdebugrc

add this:

```
set autolist
set autoeval
set autoreload
```

credit to (and more info) here: http://pivotallabs.com/users/chad/blog/articles/366-ruby-debug-in-30-seconds-we-don-t-need-no-stinkin-gui-